# Set up iMessage on iPod touch without erasing all data

Tags: messages

My dad has been trying to set up iMessage on my sisters iPod touch so my sister can text me. How do I sign in to iMessage on my iPod?

People have said to clear out all of the data, but we have not done so because all of the apps and contacts will be erased.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings → Messages and log in with your Apple ID. This does not erase any data.